# How to get the argo workflow age in seconds using kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, argo-workflows

Is there a way to fetch a specific argo workflow age in seconds using `kubectl` command?

I've a requirement for comparing the argo workflow age. If the workflow age is greater than 24 hours I need to terminate the workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use [Argo Workflow's built-in, declarative timeout feature](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/timeouts-workflow.yaml):

```yaml
spec:
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 86400
```

That will fail the workflow if it takes over 24 hours. To actually delete the workflow, set a [TTL policy](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/cost-optimisation.md#limit-the-total-number-of-workflows-and-pods).

```yaml
ttlStrategy:
  secondsAfterCompletion: 60
```

The [cost optimizations](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/cost-optimisation.md#limit-the-total-number-of-workflows-and-pods) docs have some other notes which will be helpful when designing your cleanup strategy.

I can never resist a good `jq` challenge, so here's a script-based alternative:

```sh
WORKFLOW_NAME=something

if kubectl get wf -n argo "$WORKFLOW_NAME" -ojson | jq --exit-status 'now - (.metadata.creationTimestamp | fromdateiso8601) > (24*60*60)'; then
  kubectl delete wf -n argo "$WORKFLOW_NAME"
fi
```

Comment: Does this `activeDeadlineSeconds: 86400` takes care of deleting running workflow after 24 hours automatically?

Comment: @Biru good question! It will not. Update the answer with that info.

Comment: The another example for ttlStrategy can be found in the script - https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/gc-ttl.yaml